# Cordova can't find my Java installation, but JAVA_HOME looks valid. What's going on?

Tags: java, windows, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Windows 7 64-bit, with 64-bit JDK.  Cordova plugman 1.4.2-dev.  Using cygwin bash as a shell, but I don't see why that would affect anything.

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25"

$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

$ ls "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25"
bin        include         lib          release
COPYRIGHT  javafx-src.zip  LICENSE      THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
db         jre             README.html  THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt

$ ./main.js install --platform android --project ../myproject/ --plugin phonegap-facebook-plugin-gtg --variable APP_ID="1155264567919069" --variable APP_NAME="Voice Test"
Fetching plugin "phonegap-facebook-plugin-gtg" via npm
Installing "phonegap-facebook-plugin" for android
Failed to install 'phonegap-facebook-plugin':CordovaError: Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25"
```

I've also tried using JAVA_HOME without the quotes.  What's going on?

Comment: add the path to `jdk1.8.0_25\bin` to your PATH.

Comment: Did you set JDK on your environment variable?

Comment: @Omore - If I understand you correctly, yes, the JAVA_HOME points to a JDK.

Comment: give path like this c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin as @cubrr mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cubrr gave the correct answer in the comments.  The error message being produced by Cordova is extremely misleading: the problem isn't that JAVA_HOME was incorrect, but that `javac` wasn't on my path. This was made all the more confusing by the fact that `java` *was* on my path, so when I checked it gave correct results.  This is because the Oracle installer adds a directory to your path (`c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`) that contains links to `java.exe` and related programs but not the relevant JDK programs.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! Make sure you accept your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

1) set > system variables > path to

```
 `;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_xxx\bin;`
```

2) create new JAVA_HOME path with the value

```
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_xxx
```

now check javac version by issuing command at CMD

```
   javac -version
```

*** don't touch the oracle - "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;" path

Answer (score 0):

If you are running windows 10, you need to restart your computer after changing the path and other variables. Possibly also on earlier windows versions.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer, please make sure to complete the [tour] before answering questions!